# How can I find why Thread block?

Tags: jprofiler

[image]

This picture is a part of my pressure test, it looks fine in the previous part, but block for an unknown reason, how can I know what going on between my bookmark area? What causes the block.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself, In Thread Monitor I can find this blocked thread are all cause by IO Logger print